# android calling clone simple_list_item_1

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a list that calls simple_list_item_1, 
now I want to customise this cell, to include an image,
but I have problems calling it

this is the working code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   //mira el life cycle, aqui y el de createView!
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // la manera con sencillo
         ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title); //using Android own simple 

        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);


    }
```

but now , i need to call, the cloned `simple_list_item_1`

that is already inside my layout folder, the name of the clone is simple_list_item.xml

so how to call my cloned list item?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What problem are you facing while calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 1):

You should create class that extended from ArrayAdapter and do inflating your item and populate it after. If you need I can give some code example.

**UPD:**

For example like that :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater infalter = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = infalter.inflate(YOUR_LAYOUT_ITEM, parent, false);
        //v.findViewById(ID_YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW).setDrawable.... and so on...

        return v;
    }
```

Its the most simple code. In real project you should use some tricks to achive much perfomance like holder and using convertView.

Of course you should change your code in your Activity like this :

```
ListView listView;   
ArrayList<Object> objects;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
        listView = findViewById(ID_LISTVIEW_IN_ACTIVITY);
        MyAdapter myListAdapter = new MyAdapter<Object>(getActivity(),
                YOUR_LAYOUT_ITEM, objects);

        listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }
```

Good luck!